# Disable event click on Google Map v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I add  custom Google Maps Info Window for my GMap v3
How to disable 'click' event  when i click on InfoWindow content and InfoWindow close button ?

Example code i puts on  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwLdxG

```
function InfoBox(opts) {
    google.maps.OverlayView.call(this);
    this.latlng_ = opts.latlng;
    this.map_ = opts.map;
    this.content = opts.content;
    this.offsetVertical_ = -195;
    this.offsetHorizontal_ = 5;
    this.height_ = 165;
    this.width_ = 266;
    var me = this;
    this.boundsChangedListener_ =
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.map_, "bounds_changed", function () {
            return me.panMap.apply(me);
        });
    // Once the properties of this OverlayView are initialized, set its map so
    // that we can display it. This will trigger calls to panes_changed and
    // draw.
    this.setMap(this.map_);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial solution. Didn't want to spend time going through and learning about InfoBoxes - Infowindow would have been solved.

The following will remove the click event when you click/open a infoBOX. you need to find a way to re-add when closing the InfoBOX. InfoBox != Infowindow, I have no API to do it.

you need to add/change:

ADD: `var listener` to the top of script;

CHANGE:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

              alert("google.maps.event.addListener");
            });
```

to

```
 listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
          alert("google.maps.event.addListener");
        });
```

Change:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], "click", function (e) {
            var infoBox = new InfoBox({
                latlng: this.getPosition(),
                map: map,
                content: this.content
            });
            google.maps.event.removeListener(listener)
          });
```

To

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], "click", function (e) {
        var infoBox = new InfoBox({
            latlng: this.getPosition(),
            map: map,
            content: this.content
        });
        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener)
      });
```

**CODEPEN:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwLrYJ?editors=0010